# Is it possible to map an O365 Sharepoint folder as a drive on a VM (for all users of the VM)?

Tags: azure, sharepoint, microsoft-office-365, entra-id, mappeddrive

Is there a good way to map an O365 Sharepoint folder as a drive (for all users of an Azure VM)?

Ideally, a way where frequent re-authentication by a specific user is not required and the users's permissions translate from the logged in user.

(Note: AAD DS user accounts are already used to log into the Azure VM.)

Thanks!

Comment: Note: While I am able to map to the O365 sharepoint site  (https://corpname.sharepoint.com/myO365Group/Shared%20Documents/myFolder) from my local desktop (after changing the automatic login settings in IE), I get an error when doing the same thing from the Azure VM.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this working for a single users, but not for all users.

Apparently, on Windows Server 2012R2 you need to enable the desktop experience before you can map to SharePoint libraries:

Server Manager > Add Roles and Features > Features > User Interfaces and Infrastructure > Desktop Experience

After that, you need to add the URL to Trusted Sites, and log in using IE (check yes for "remember me"). Then set IE to log in automatically "Internet Options > Security Settings (Local Intranet) > Scroll to bottom > Automatic logon only in Intranet zone".